# Running a live radio app background

Tags: android

I made an app which is going live with Vitamio. I also forward to Facebook page of the radio when click on the button but streaming is stopping. I want to proceed with live broadcasting. My code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button startButton,facebookButton,twitterButton;
private VideoView videoView;
private String httpLiveUrl = "http://someURL.m3u8";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.setTitle("Standart FM");

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBasla);
    facebookButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebook);
    twitterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTwitter);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));

    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(MainActivity.this))
        return  ;


    new getStream().execute();

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(videoView.isPlaying()){
                 videoView.pause();
                 startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.andplaybtn);
             }else{
                 startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.andstopbtn);
                 videoView.start();

             }
        }
    });

    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/StandartFM"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

How to run in background in spite of the click and opening the browser?

Comment: Use android services http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class

Comment: No no no . my application is streaming. I want to run it when i clicked and opened the radio's facebook. Because when i clicked to facebook button radio straming is paused.

Comment: Write that radio in Service not in activity and call it from your Activity...!

Comment: How can i use VideoView component in Service? No layout there in Service.

Comment: write Videoview programatically...

Comment: Service is the BEST solution for streaming audio and video http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices